# C++ Can I overload the bracket [] operator to do different things if it on the LHS vs RHS of an assignment?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am looking to accomplish the following:

`int x, y, z;`

1. `foo[x] = y;` acts like `do_this(x,y);`
2. `z = foo[x];` acts like `z = do_that(x)`

I can accomplish the first with a `Foo` class and a `Helper` class, where the `operator[]` returns by value a `Helper` class constructed with `x`, and the `operator=` for the `Helper` class is defined to run `do_this(this->x, y)`.  Like below:

```
class Foo {
    public:
    Helper operator[](int x) { 
        return Helper(x);
    }
};

class Helper {
    public: 
    Helper(x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
    void operator=(int y) {
        do_this(this->x, y);
    }
    private:
    int x;
};
```

What I can't figure out is how to accomplish (2).  Is there a way to overload the `operator[]` so that it knows if it was used on the lhs vs the rhs?

Comment: Sort of sounds like you want C++ to have *properties*, where you can provide a *getter* and *setter*.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - give your `Helper` class a conversion function to `int`:

```
class Helper {
    public: 
    Helper(x){
        this->x = x;
    }
    Helper& operator= (int y) {
        do_this(this->x, y);
        return *this;
    }
    operator int() const {
        return do_that(this->x);
    }
    private:
    int x;
};
```

This will also allow other uses like `product *= foo[x];` or `func_taking_int(foo[x])`, etc.

One potential catch is that some uses of `auto` or function templates would still just keep the type `Helper`, which might not be what's wanted - so users of `Foo` should still understand that this proxy sugar is going on. It could also be helpful to have some alternative syntax to explicitly get the `int` value for cases like that, in either `Foo` or `Helper`.

Comment: This looks good!  What does the "const" after the operator int() signify?  Also, why do I need to return a Helper& in the operator= function?

Comment: A `const` after a member function parameter list means it can be called whether or not the class is accessed as `const`. Not likely to matter here, since probably nobody would have a `const Helper`, but I put it by habit wherever possible, especially on "getters". Returning `*this` from an `operator=` makes it act more like built-in assigment expressions, in case somebody tries `int copy = foo[x] = param();` or `if ((foo[x] = param()) != 0)`, etc. - these uses would `do_this` first, and then `do_that`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood what you actually want to do, but you are might be able to use the `const` version of the `operator[]` vs. the non-`const` version. For example:

```
struct Foo {
    Z operator [] (int x) const {   // this last const is important
        return do_that(x);
    }

    Helper operator [] (int x) {
        // as you yourself have written.
    }
};
```

There are more tips and tricks to this, for forwarding arguments perfectly (a.k.a "perfect forwarding",) for being "const correct", and many other small things, but the gist of it is the above.